# Loading Google Maps API throws "Loading the Google Maps JavaScript API without a callback is not supported"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an application that makes a GET call to [`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&libraries=places`](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&libraries=places) when it tries to load the Google Maps API. I believe this is synchronously loading which is documented in the [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-sync).

However, I have been seeing the following error popping up in my automated testing environment in the last 24 hours:

> Loading the Google Maps JavaScript API without a callback is not supported: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/url-params#required_parameters

I wonder if anyone knows what's going on?

Making a GET request to [`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&libraries=places`](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&libraries=places) URL should still allow synchronously loading.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, preferably a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in the question itself.

Comment: Google have changed the requirements for this - not sure when but I found exactly this last night. Ordinarily this is easily fixed adding the `callback=initMap` to the script url which is as they suggest - when the `initMap` is within a script declared as `module` on the page then this does not work

Comment: The same error occurs on the ["sample" page documenting synchronous loading in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-sync).